# PostgreSql with php trim function unexpected behavior

Tags: php, postgresql, trim, phppgadmin

```
$str = trim($somestring);
$sql = "UPDATE project SET name = '" . $str . "' WHERE id = $id";
```

When I am using this code without the `trim()` I can see the value in postgresql field (phpPgAdmin).

But when I use `trim()`, then:

The value in phpPgAdmin seems to be blank (not `NULL`). I can echo`$str` and see it. I can also click on "Edit row" button and there I see the name field with the proper value. But I can't see it when I am browsing table content (the rows) -> then the name field is empty... Why is that?

Is this PgAdmin bug or what?

Comment: can you pls post var_dump($somestring); and var_dump($sql) when the query didnt work

Comment: What's the content of $str? Perhaps it is an issue with phpPgAdmin not escaping the field properly.

Comment: I think it's a phpPhAdmin issue, I have the same issue. I have table, and when I am browsing, I see nothing in the field, but if I select, the value is there.